# Collaborative probability

Tags: probability

If two students have the probability of 0.57 each to solve a problem correctly then what is the probability that they will solve the problem correctly in collaboration?

Comment: It largely depends what happens when they do not agree, since they must say the same thing in the end.

Comment: The term *collaboration* is ambiguous in the context of this question. If you meant to ask what is the probability that either one (or both) of them will solve the question, then you can find it using *complementary event*: $1-(1-0.57)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming independence of the two students in solving the problem and that the problem can be either solved or not (e.g. one cannot have a student solve part (a) of the problem and the other one part (b) and put the two parts together):

P(solve problem in collaboration)=1-P(nobody solves the problem)

=1-P(first student does not solve the problem)P(second student does not solve the problem)

$=1-0.43^2=0.8151$